# Insert the possible combinations of two arrays in to another array in PLSQL

Tags: arrays, plsql, oracle11g

I have two arrays Course and time. I am  trying to create another array with all the possible combinations of these two arrays. For eg:

```
DECLARE
type course_array
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
type time_array
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
type combination_array
IS
  TABLE OF NUMBER;
  Course_pref course_array;
  Time_pref time_array;
  combination combination_array;
BEGIN
  Course_pref := course_array(1, 2, 4);
  Time_pref   := time_array(1, 2, 3, 5);
```

I want the an array which would look like

```
combination:= combination_array((1,1),(1,2),(1,4),(2,1),(2,2),(2,4)......)
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a solution better than O(n^2)? If not, you could just loop over all values of array1 and for each value, loop over all values of array2 and then insert (i, j) into the third array. Oh and the third array shouldn't be of type NUMBER. Instead it should probably be of an Object type which is defined over two NUMBER variables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this function would be a better approach to it. *(untested code!!)*

```
DECLARE

type course_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
type time_array   IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

function combination_function(i number, j number) return number is 

  t_i number := 1 + trunc( (i-1) / time_array.last);
  c_i number := 1 + ((i-1) mod course_array.last);

begin

  if i <= (course_array.last * time_array.last) then
    return(decode(j, 1, time_array(t_i), 
                     2, course_array(c_i)));
  else
    return(null);
  end if;

end;

BEGIN

  Course_pref := course_array(1, 2, 4);
  Time_pref   := time_array(1, 2, 3, 5);

  for i in 1 .. (course_array.last * time_array.last) loop
    dbms_output.put_line('('||combination_function(i, 1)||','||combination_function(i, 2)||')');
  end loop;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way is to use SQL part of the PL/SQL.

We use the powers of SQL so the types need to be SQL types. SQL types can be used in PL/SQL but not vice versa.

```
create type num_list_t is table of number;
/

create type num_pair_t is object(
    a number,
    b number
);
/

create type num_pair_list_t is table of num_pair_t;
/
```

An example how to make the combinations with SQL cross join. This is the core solution. See also e.g. [How to generate a permutations or combinations of n rows in m columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4159595/272735) You'll see later how to apply this to PL/SQL.

```
with
t1 as (
  select column_value from table(num_list_t(0,2,4,6,8))
),
t2 as (
  select column_value from table(num_list_t(1,3,5,7,9))
)
select t1.column_value as a, t2.column_value as b
from t1
cross join t2;

         A          B
---------- ----------
         0          1
         0          3
         0          5
         0          7
         0          9
         2          1
         2          3
         2          5
         2          7
         2          9
         4          1
         4          3
         4          5
         4          7
         4          9
         6          1
         6          3
         6          5
         6          7
         6          9
         8          1
         8          3
         8          5
         8          7
         8          9

25 rows selected.
```

An example how to apply the SQL example above to PL/SQL. Note how the object constructor and bulk collect are used to slurp the results to PL/SQL.

```
declare
  v_a constant num_list_t := num_list_t(10, 20, 30, 40);
  v_b constant num_list_t := num_list_t(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
  v_c num_pair_list_t;

  function combine(p_a in num_list_t, p_b in num_list_t) return num_pair_list_t is
    v_res num_pair_list_t := num_pair_list_t();
  begin
    with
    t1 as (
      select column_value from table(p_a)
    ),
    t2 as (
      select column_value from table(p_b)
    )
    select num_pair_t(t1.column_value, t2.column_value)
      bulk collect into v_res
    from t1
    cross join t2;

    return v_res;
  end;

  procedure print(p_list in num_pair_list_t) is
  begin
    for i in 1 .. p_list.last
    loop
      dbms_output.put_line('(' || p_list(i).a || ',' || p_list(i).b || ')');
    end loop;
  end;
begin
  v_c := combine(v_a, v_b);
  print(v_c);

  print(combine(num_list_t(34,68), num_list_t(12,24)));
end;
/

(0,1)
(0,3)
(0,5)
(0,7)
(0,9)
(2,1)
(2,3)
(2,5)
(2,7)
(2,9)
(4,1)
(4,3)
(4,5)
(4,7)
(4,9)
(6,1)
(6,3)
(6,5)
(6,7)
(6,9)
(8,1)
(8,3)
(8,5)
(8,7)
(8,9)
(34,12)
(34,24)
(68,12)
(68,24)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...if I want to store the combination values in a 2d array so that I can iterate through the array to compare it with some condition. How will I do that. For example if my final array looks something like the following:

Comment: comb:= array((1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(2,1),......) 
Can I do something like this: 
if         
comb(1)(2) > some condition 
then 
Some statement

Comment: I am sorry if i am not making myself clear enough. I want to store the final combination values in a 2d array so that I can compare the values of the array with some condition later.

Comment: @Zubair That's worth of a new question. You can refer to this question/answer in your new question. Remember to describe the comparison logic in details.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help...but my initial question was if I can insert the final combination values into an array.

Comment: @Zubair err ... in this answer the combination values are in an array (in a form of tuples). I'm sorry but I fail to see how that fail to answer the question. Or do you would like to see an array of arrays instead ?

Comment: I regret that I did not quite understand your explanation...I am a newbie in this field...If you could tell me how to insert the values as an array inside another array. So that when I want to print a particular value from the array 'combination' i can do something like this combination(2)(1). 
 
I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Zubair In that case please help yourself and study the subject a bit more. One good resource in addition of Oracle's own documentation is e.g. [Working with Collections](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html).

Comment: Thanks for the link...i will go through it.